# How do you find python package metadata information given a module

Tags: python, python-importlib

I'm trying to retrieve metadata information for a python package given the name of the module.

I can use importlib-metadata to retrieve the information, but in some cases the top-level module name is not the same as the package name.

example:

```
>>> importlib_metadata.metadata('zmq')['License']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "c:\Users\xxxxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\Lib\site-packages\importlib_metadata\__init__.py", line 499, in metadata
    return Distribution.from_name(distribution_name).metadata
  File "c:\Users\xxxxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\Lib\site-packages\importlib_metadata\__init__.py", line 187, in from_name
    raise PackageNotFoundError(name)
importlib_metadata.PackageNotFoundError: zmq


>>> importlib_metadata.metadata('pyzmq')['License']
'LGPL+BSD'
```

Comment: Some ideas: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60363617/11138259 -- https://stackoverflow.com/a/60351412/11138259

Comment: For others who come past here (via Google etc.) check out [this other discussion][1] for more ideas based on @sinoroc's suggestion.
  [1]: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63847850/python3-pip-find-which-package-provides-a-particular-module/63887567#63887567

Answer (score 3):

I believe something like the following should work:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import importlib.util
import pathlib

import importlib_metadata

def get_distribution(file_name):
    result = None
    for distribution in importlib_metadata.distributions():
        try:
            relative = (
                pathlib.Path(file_name)
                .relative_to(distribution.locate_file(''))
            )
        except ValueError:
            pass
        else:
            if relative in distribution.files:
                result = distribution
    return result

def alpha():
    file_name = importlib.util.find_spec('easy_install').origin
    distribution = get_distribution(file_name)
    print("alpha", distribution.metadata['Name'])

def bravo():
    file_name = importlib_metadata.__file__
    distribution = get_distribution(file_name)
    print("bravo", distribution.metadata['Name'])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    alpha()
    bravo()
```

---

***Update*** (February 2021):

Looks like this could become easier thanks to the newly added `packages_distributions()` function in `importlib_metadata`:

- https://importlib-metadata.readthedocs.io/en/stable/using.html#package-distributions
- https://github.com/python/importlib_metadata/pull/287/files

Comment: This assumes the path of the toplevel modules are subdirectories of the package. zmq and pyzmq-<version>.dist-info are both subdirectories of site-packages.

Comment: @nsk I do not understand the issue. As a test I just installed `pyzmq` and the above code seems to work perfectly fine.

Comment: @nsk Did that answer your question or is there still some clarification needed?

Comment: Nice solution. The only thing I would add is there is a `is_relative_to` method that can slightly simplify things.

Comment: I spoke too soon: unfortunately, because so many packages are just eggs in e.g. /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/, this fails.

Comment: @Noldorin Ah right, if the code is installed in / imported from an archive (egg, zip file, etc.) then things might go wrong. Maybe there are ways to deal with this, I should look into this.

Comment: @Noldorin If you know the top level package (or module) then you can use this: https://importlib-metadata.readthedocs.io/en/stable/using.html#package-distributions

Comment: @sinoroc Yep, that's what I ended up doing, cheers. I also came up with a general solution though, which I've posted as an answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a function that does what you want, I believe. It's not terribly efficient, in that it has to enumerate all the installed package distributions and read the list of top-level modules for each — however, I believe it's the best one can do. (Of course, you can also cache a dict mapping from top-level module names to package names.)

```py
from importlib.metadata import Distribution, distributions
from pathlib import Path
from typing import *

def get_pkg_distribution(top_level_module: str) -> Optional[Distribution]:
    pkg_path = Path(__file__).parent
    for dist in distributions():
        package_namespaces = (dist.read_text("top_level.txt") or "").splitlines()
        if top_level_module in package_namespaces:
            return dist
    return None

# Get the package metadata for the current package. Note, `__package__` is actually the name of the top-level module!
pkg_metadata = dict(get_pkg_distribution(__package__).metadata.items())
__version__ = pkg_metadata["Version"]
```

Comment: This solution seems to have the same shortcomings as mine. In that it relies on filenames. It would be better to rely on fully qualified module name, get the top level package/module name and then compare with https://importlib-metadata.readthedocs.io/en/stable/using.html#package-distributions

Comment: Actually, my solution is very similar to the implementation of `packages_distributions`, having just looked at the source code for that lib! I believe `__package` should get the full-qualified name of the top-level module? Not 100% sure though. Does the trick for me.

Comment: Does it work for code that is installed as egg, or something like that?

Comment: It seemed to when I last tried... but I can investigate properly later, maybe.

Comment: Yes, please let me know if you manage to test. I really wonder how to get a valid `__file__` out of an egg.

Comment: @sinoroc Oh, I see what you mean now... I didn't manage to test that. Have you tried `__package__` from within an egg/wheel though? Or if not that, then maybe the `inspect` module?