# Get version of Python poetry project from inside the project

Tags: python, python-packaging, python-poetry

I have a python library packaged using poetry. I have the following requirements

Inside the poetry project

```py
# example_library.py
def get_version() -> str:
    # return the project version dynamically. Only used within the library

def get_some_dict() -> dict:
    # meant to be exported and used by others
    return {
        "version": get_version(),
        "data": #... some data
    }
```

In the host project, I want the following test case to pass no matter which version of `example_library` I'm using

```py
from example_library import get_some_dict
import importlib.metadata
version = importlib.metadata.version('example_library')

assert get_some_dict()["version"] == version
```

I have researched ideas about reading the `pyproject.toml` file but I'm not sure how to make the function read the toml file regardless of the library's location.

The [Poetry API](https://github.dev/python-poetry/poetry) doesn't really help either, because I just want to read the top level TOML file from within the library and get the version number, not create one from scratch.

Comment: Question asked many times. Use `import importlib.metadata; version = importlib.metadata.version('ProjectName')`. This is not specific to Poetry. Make sure that `ProjectName` is installed (editable installation is also good enough of course). [Documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.metadata.html#distribution-versions).

Comment: Seems like your code is meant to run in the project that imports the library. What I meant was: let's say we have a package called `file_processing`. Within `file_processing`, I have a function `file_processing.get_file_processing_version()`. I want its return value to be dynamic and I want to call this function within the library so this is independent of any host project.

Comment: What's the difference? This will also work to get the version of itself. -- Or I misunderstood your point.

Comment: Sorry. I have tried your suggestion and it works. Post it as an answer and I'll accept it or I can just delete this question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `importlib.metadata.version()` from Python's own standard library:

```py
import importlib.metadata

version = importlib.metadata.version('ProjectName')
```

This is not specific to Poetry and will work for any project (library or application) whose metadata is readable.

Make sure that `ProjectName` is installed. Where `ProjectName` can be your own library or a 3rd party library, it does not matter. And note that a so-called "editable" installation is also good enough.

[Documentation for *`importlib.metadata.version()`*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.metadata.html#distribution-versions).

See also:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/65594622